# flutter-firestore: how to total unread messages for badge count

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, count

I'd like to show the number of unread messages on chat icon in a page of my flutter-firestore app.
For that, I save unread message `docId`s inside each `chatRoomId`. I can count each number for each `chatRoomId` respectively, but can't count all number for all `chatRoomId`s to show total number of unread messages of a user like in above picture.
The following is my firestore structure. For example, as you see in the screenshot, if I want to count all `docId`s and create `3` in a red circle on the chat badge, how can I do that in code?

[image]

Here is what I can do so far to create that badge count.

```
int _getUnseenMessagesNumber(List<Map<String, dynamic>> items) {
int counter = 0;
for (final item in items) {
  counter += item.values.first.length;
}
return counter;
```

}

```
body: StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('crews')
                  .doc(uid)
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                int number = _getUnseenMessagesNumber(
                            snapshot.data['chatRoomIds']);
                if (snapshot.data['chatRoomIds'].isNotEmpty) {
                  return Stack(children: [
                    Container(
                       decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.red),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          number.toString()
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]);
                } else {
                  return container();
                }
              }),
```

Comment: you can try to use an array of Map like [roomID: [docID1, Docid2], roomID2: [docID3],...] instead of creating a field each time there is a new room with unseen messages

Comment: @ArnaudDelubac Thanks Amaud, I edited my question with a new firestore structure as you suggested. Now how can I change my code to get the result of counting all `docId`s within `'chatRoomIds'` field in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok then if you changed the structure of your document so that the unseen messages are in a list of Map, then should be able to extract the number of unseen messages with some function like this:

```dart
int _getUnseenMessagesNumber(List<Map<String, dynamic>> items){
 int counter = 0;
 for(final item in test) {
    counter+=item.values.first.length;
 }
 return counter;
 }
```

I hope it helped

Comment: I edited my question with my new code. When I run the app, I have an error saying `type '_internallinkedhashmap string dynamic ' is not a subtype of type 'list dynamic' `. How can I resolve this?

Comment: change the if (snapshot.data['chatRoomIds'].isNotEmpty) to if(snapshot.hasData) and put the line intnumber = ... inside the if block